# How can i determine related posts based on tags and post title?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, blogs, hashtag

Can anyone tell me how i can get PHP & SQL to determine related posts that are similar to the current based on a title and tags?

Comment: So what you are looking for is an explanation of an algorithm which rates blog posts of relevance based on the tags and title?

Answer (score 2):

You split title in words , drop ones that are shorter then 3 symbols, and query the database.
And then you query DB for all the posts with same tags as the current post.

This question is way to vague.